# Categorical Intra-Cluster Quality - Suggestions

Tags: machine-learning, clustering

I've derived some clusters from categorical data using a few of different methods - k-medians, k-modes, k-medoids, etc etc.

I've used validation-style methods for the determination of optimal k. The validation methods agree on $k^*$, however, I'd like to assess intra-cluster quality.

So, for example, I'd like to test the homogeneity/entropy/purity of a cluster, but I've not had luck finding examples of this.

When I looked for entropy, it was as a form of external validation (when true classes were available).

So, I'd really appreciate if anyone had any suggestions and links for how to assess intra-cluster quality in R, please.

Answer (score 0):

Based on a distance measure (e.g., simple matching distance) you can compute the silhouettes and plot them (R-command `silhouette`). You can also have a look at `cluster.stats` and `clusterboot` in package `fpc`.

Comment: Hi @ChristianHennig. Thanks for your input and expertise on the matters. However, my understanding is that clusterboot is about 'stability' subject to some permutation. I've seen stuff like this regarding percentage of overlap etc. However, Is there anything which gives within-cluster score for information quality, homogeneity, purity, correlation?

Comment: The distance metric would be either Hamming or Manhattan, most likely.

Comment: @EB3112 (a) clusterboot gives stability values for each cluster individually. You may read the paper cited in the documentation to understand what exactly it does. (Of course if you're not interested in stability, that won't help you.) (b) Both the silhouette and cluster.stats run on any distance you want.

Comment: Thanks @Christian. I'll read up on it in closer detail. Any personal thoughts on the merits of using information-theorteic measures?

Comment: @EB3112 That's too unspecific a question. What measure, and for what aim exactly? My opinions on these things can depend a lot on specifics of the case, of which I have no idea right now. Chances are this would rather be something for another "regular" question rather than the comments section.

Comment: Hi @Christian. I am essentially looking for something like this, going back to my earlier point. https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/figure/10.1080/03610926.2021.1914660?scroll=top&needAccess=true